# Error sending application to IOS though eclipse

Tags: codenameone

Im trying to send a sample application to my iOS device (iPhone XS), I created the Certificates and the provisioning files in Control Center > Device > iOS > Signing, but when I send the App to 'Send iOS Debug' the build in the portal site cloud.codenameone.com has an error, Im not able to see any relevant issues in the log, except the below can you please advise:

- I don't have Xcode open

Error log.

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Tracker.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.
[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
[!] Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo. Since CDN is now used as the default, you may safely remove it from your repos directory via `pod repo remove master`. To suppress this warning please add `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` to your Podfile.
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.
[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
[!] Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo. Since CDN is now used as the default, you may safely remove it from your repos directory via `pod repo remove master`. To suppress this warning please add `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` to your Podfile.
Process return code is 0

Comment: This isn't the portion that includes the error. I need to see the full log to help you with that. Notice that  you can place the link to the error log in our on-site chat  and we can also help you with it from there.

Comment: Hi Shai thanks for your reply, I fixed the issue by regenerating the certificates through the wizard. Thanks